Suppose $a>0, b>0$, then prove that $a^a+b^b \geq a^b+b^a$
I’m trying to figure out this proof that
$$a^a+b^b \geq a^b+b^a.$$
What I can do is find some easy examples but I can’t prove it.
For example:
$$2^2+3^3>2^3+3^2$$
But I have no idea how to go on.

This has been asked and answered before: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/410895/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1302691/42969 – found with Approach0
